# how to reset counter on button click in react

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react project and I have a counter. I have added the functionality so that the counter will reset when it reaches 0 but I also want to have the functionality if the button is clicked.

I have tried doing it but the results are something different.

This is what happens when the countdown reaches 0 and resets to 10 again:
[image]

but this is what happens when i click the button it resets the countdown to 10 but the countdown is somewhat different:
[image]

here is my code:

```
 const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(10);

React.useEffect(() => {
    counter > 0 && setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    if (counter === 0) {
        setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1);
        setCounter(20);
    }
}, [counter]);
```

[image]

here is the code to reset the counter on button click:

```
 const handleAnswerOptionClick = (isCorrect) => {
    const nextQuestion = currentQuestion + 1;
    if (nextQuestion < questions.length) {
        setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
        setCounter(10);
    } else {
        setShowScore(true);
    }
};
```

and here is the html for it:

```
<div className="answer_div">
                    {questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map(
                        (answerOption) => (
                            <button
                                onClick={() =>
                                    handleAnswerOptionClick(
                                        answerOption.isCorrect
                                    )
                                }
                            >
                                {answerOption.answerText}
                            </button>
                        )
                    )}
                </div>
```

[image]

[image]

how can i make the counter behave normally on button click.

Comment: Maybe you can write down your code instead of posting screenshots so that one can reproduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I created a sandbox that shows one correct way to handle your problem.](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-dewdney-eqy27?file=/src/App.js)

Why is your code not working?
Because every time you force set the counter with the  `setCounter(10);` you are triggering the `useEffect`. The problem is that timeout you triggered in the previous call to `useEffect` is still running. So you are effectively running 2 (or more) `useEffect` concurrently.

Every time you call `useEffect` you need to check if there is a pending timeout and eventually clear it.

```
  const timerRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timerRef.current) {
      clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
      timerRef.current = null;
    }

    if (counter > 0) {
      timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    }

    if (counter === 0) {
      setCurrentQuestion(currentQuestion + 1);
      setCounter(10);
    }
  }, [counter]);
```

In this example I am storing the reference of every timeout I create in a React's `ref`. And then when I enter again in `useEffect` I check if there is any pending timeout and clear it. This way I can now set a new timer that will be the only one running.

To give you a full explanation, the timeouts in your code will show the wrong numbers because every timeout call will use their version of the `counter` state. The one in the moment when the `useEffect` that created the timeout was run! So you are actually see values from the past :D.

Answer (score 1):

we need a sandbox however, try using setInterval instead , also consider adding a cleanup function to your use effect, also your state update is depending on the previous state , consider using the function patter `setCounter((state)=> state-1)`

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
     const interval = setInterval(()=>{
    setCounter((state)=>{
    if(state>0){
    return state-1
    }
    
    });
    // cleanup
      return ()=> clearInterval(interval);
    },1000)
   
}, [counter]);
```